# Swift SearchResultsController Segue - "Receiver ... has no segue with identifier 'testSeg''"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, uisearchcontroller

I am having issues segueing from a searchResultController to another viewcontroller

From the beginning:
I have three controllers, A UIViewController with a CollectionView and UISearchController embedded inside, a UITableViewController which will act as the searchResultController and the final UIViewController that each tableview cell will segue to when clicked. [Here is an image of Main.Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqpIA.png). 
[Here the segue with its identifier is shown, which is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfRy5.png).

**The segue is linked from the SearchResultsTableViewController itself, not the tableviewcell**
Once I click on a search result, I perform that Segue from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in the SearchResultsController. However, I get the "Receiver ... has no segue with identifier 'testSeg''" error.

For clarity, the names of the controllers and their roles are:

1) DiscoverViewController: (contains UISearchController and CollectionView)

2) SearchResultsTableViewController (Acts as the searchResultsController which correctly filters and updates any data. Each cell is supposed to segue from this controller)

3) UIViewController (A simple UIViewController which is the destination of the segue)

The issue is with the segue, everything else performs as intended. This is the code for the SearchResultsTableViewController.

**Note: You can disregard the fact that this is Swift 3. I attempted this using Swift 2.3 and got the same error**

```
private let reuseIdentifer = "searchCell"

class SearchResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var searchResults: [String]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.tableView!.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifer)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return (searchResults?.count)!
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifer, for: indexPath) 
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSeg", sender: self)
}
}
```

The searchResults array comes from the DiscoverViewController. Everything works fine except for the segue. Upon selecting a row, the app crashes with error:

```
2016-10-07 12:17:51.216 MultiTestDemo[1028:10002] *** Terminating app
due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Receiver (<MultiTestDemo.SearchResultsTableViewController: 
0x7fea214055f0>) has no segue with identifier 'testSeg''
```

I've made sure that there were no spaces or anything in the segue Identifier. I even copied it directly to the SearchResultsTableViewController's didselectrowatindexpath function.

To conclude, what I am asking for is help as to why the SearchResultsTableViewController can no longer identify the segue (or any segue with any identifier) when I connected in IB. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you instantiate the SearchResultsTableViewController?

Comment: Found it in your GitHub link.  The problem stems from how you instantiate the SearchResultsTableViewController.  This line: `let searchResultsController = SearchResultsTableViewController()` creates it, but without any reference to the storyboard - it therefore "knows" nothing about the segue defined in the storyboard.  You should instead use the UIStoryboard method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` (having added an identifier for it in the storyboard if necessary).

Comment: This definitely works. I had actually tried this before, but it continued to crash until i removed a repeat instantiation in the searchREsultsController. Thank you for the answer. However, it appears that there is no "way back". I realize there is no navigation controller in the demo, but how exactly would a user get back to the search results, if say for example, this was a search-for-user function? A previous implementation I had worked and allowed for a way back but using a searchResultsController causes complications when there needs to be a way back.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear, you don´t have any segue with the identifier `testSeg`. Click on the segue and then on the right menu go to attributes inspector and add the identifier `testSeg` to it.

Comment: You have the segue, but you have to set the identifier for it.

Comment: I have set the identifier. Please take a look at the second picture. in my question. It's a link at the beginning of the question which is an image of my storyboard. I have the segue and the identifier

Comment: Then restart xcode and clean the project and rerun.

Comment: Can you upload your project to Dropbox or google drive and send the link and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I uploaded it to Github. Here it is: https://github.com/ChrishonWyllie/MultiTestDemo. You can disregard the swift files with a '2' in them. Those were simply new versions I had been testing out

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. I add new segue and new unwind segue, define an identifiers, test my app and get same error for both new segues

> Receiver <...> has no segue with identifier '...'

I solved it.
In my case the problem was that I mistakenly had two instances of the same class in two storyboards, Main.Storyboard(Base) and Main.Storyboard(English). A new segues was exist only in one of storyboard. 
I don't need two storyboard so I just remove Main.Storyboard(English) and it's solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide us with some code as well... thanks in advance!

Comment: I remove Main.Storyboard(English), there wasn't any changes in code...thanks!